# how to continues loop through string and return character of given index?

Tags: c#, string

```
string myinput = "ABC";
int inputLoopIndex = 5;
```

now output should be char output = `B`

I tried like

```
string myinput = "ABC";
char mycharachter;
for (int i = 0; i <= inputLoopIndex ; i++)
{
    mycharachter = myinput[i];
}
```

Error - `Index out of bound`

Comment: why if index is 5 output = `B`? please explain what is the logic you are trying to do.. the exception is correct because you are accessing an index that does not exist in the string

Comment: I assume its supposed to be modulo the length of the string.

Comment: its just an input - inputLoopIndex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string myinput = "ABC";
char mycharachter;
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    mycharachter = mystring[i % mystring.Length];
}
```

You want to use the modulo (`%`) operator, which can be used effectively to loop round (it gets the remainder). [Read more about it on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the iterator overflowing the length of the array

```
string myinput = "ABC";
char mycharachter;
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    int theIndex = i % mystring.Length;
    mycharachter = mystring[theIndex];
}
```